# How to increase opacity of an image when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout, navbar

I have a fixed top bar / nav bar on my website and in the center I have a logo. I want this logo to start off as hidden when a user comes to the page. As the user scrolls down (around 200 pixels), I want this logo to fade in. When they scroll back up to the top, I want the logo to fade back out.

Here is the script I'm using right now:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 100){
             $('#logo').fadeIn(1000);   
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

There are two problems:

1) The nav-bar to the right of the logo is also starting off as invisible and fading in, though I don't want it to (it doesn't have id=logo). I'm not sure why this is happening.

Edit: I've discovered this is happening because the #logo css has to be set to display:none in order for the fadeIn to work. This throws off the formatting. I want to use visibility:hidden instead but the javascript doesn't work with this for some reason. Still not solved, but some more info on the issue.

2) The logo is not fading out when I scroll back up. I know I need to use the fadeOut function but when I tried basically reversing the fadeIn function, I got some funky results.

Here is my site url: http://bestdressedghetto.com/displayPosts.php

And here is a snippet of the relevant topBar code (it is a php file that is included in all the pages that should have a top-bar....the javascript code above is in displayPosts.php):

```
<header>

<center><a href="displayPosts.php" id="logo">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="images/bdg-logo-floral.png" />
</a></center>

<nav style="display:block">

<a style="font-size:30px; position: relative; top: -5px;" href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>

<ul>

<li><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-link" href="displayTapes.php">Tapes</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Subscribe</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>

</ul>

</nav>

</header>
```

Any and all help is very-well appreciated!

Comment: `<center>`..... *shutter*

Comment: Haha @Ohgodwhy... anyway, 1 piece of help is that the `<center>` tag has been deprecated as of HTML4: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FElement%2Fcenter

Comment: @kunalbhat Hah. Yeah I figured that was coming. A bit of a newcomer at this stuff. Sorry for another question, but What's the best way to center an inline image in your experience? The auto margin trick only seems to work for block elements.

Comment: You can add a `display: block;` to your `<a>` tag (since it isn't by default), and use your `margin: 0 auto;` to center it (as long as it has a fixed width). I suggest removing the image from the markup (this may be debatable, but I don't believe 'images' are content, so you could safely keep that in your CSS as bg for your `<a>` tag.

Comment: @kunalbhat Never mind...figured it out. (wrapped the image/link in a <p> tag and used text-align: center)

Comment: Any help on the initial fadeIn/fadeOut issues?

Comment: I'll add an 'answer', hopefully no one downvotes it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, I am understanding you correctly... if you want the logo to fadeout once you scroll back up, you'll need to add the following to your script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 100){
          $('#logo').fadeIn(1000);   
        } else {
          $('#logo').fadeOut(1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great. I am still having in issue with the display:none however. Since this throws off the formatting, it is making the links in my nav bar appear invisible). I want to use visibility:hidden instead of display:none so that the #logo holds its place while it's not there...but this javascript doesn't seem to allow me to do that. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your link looks like you go it! Feel free to upvote if you think this helped slightly.

Comment: Yeah I just got it. Unfortunately I can't upvote yet since I don't have enough reputation :( Sorry.

Comment: Is there any way to make that javascript run only on desktop, and not on a mobile device. Basically using @media tags for the javascript? I'm trying to mess around with the different elements and manipulate them via CSS, but wondering if there's an easier way? (not very good with JS)

Answer (score 0):

A gradual fade in could be done like this

```
headerFade = function() {
    var maxScrollDistance = 200;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var percentage = $(document).scrollTop() / maxScrollDistance;
        $('nav').css('opacity', percentage);
    });
}
headerFade();


nav{opacity:0;}
```